# How select data with AND condition to many rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `cars_colors (car_id integer,color_id integer).` That shows - which colors does car have.  Example of data:

```
car_id, color_id
151, 1
151, 2
151, 8
190, 1
190, 2
190, 3
```

That means - Car №151 has colors with ids 1,2,8 and Car №190 has colors with ids 1,2,3.

I need query that will show car_id for cars, that have ALL some color_id.

Example: I need all cars with 1 and 2 color_id, I should return car_id 151,190

**NOTE:** I should define color_id in query simple - such as `in (1,2,3....99,100)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select car_id
from car_colors
where color_id in (1, 2)
group by car_id
having count(distinct color_id) = 2;
```

EDIT:

The general form of this approach looks like this:

```
select car_id
from car_colors
group by car_id
having sum(case when color_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when color_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when color_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This is an example where you require colors 1 and 2 but do not allow color 3.  You can probably see how to generalize this for a wide variety of different possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. To tell the truth, also I need condition with NEGATIVE color_id. That means - cars, that don't have some colors. I think use your query with negative subquery